# How to set timezone with react-native TimeAgo

Tags: react-native, timezone, timeago

I am building a, let's say, chat app. The timezone on my server (API) is UTC. If I save a new message the created_at date in the MySQL-database is set correctly by Laravel.

In my app I am using [TimeAgo](https://github.com/TylerLH/react-native-timeago) to display, when the message has been posted. At the moment I am in Egypt and here is UTC+2. The iOS-Simulator on my MacBook has the correct timezone (UTC+2). But TimeAgo is ignoring this timezone.

Recently message are always posted ***2 hours ago***.

The app is used from different timezones, so I can't change the timezone of the server. I have to handle the difference directly in the app depending on the device's settings.

Answer (score 0):

When determining a "time ago" - time zones are irrelevant.  It doesn't even matter what time zone your system is set to, or what time zone the application is running in.  It is always, by definition, a UTC-Now to UTC-Then comparison.  It only matters that the clock on the system that took the timestamp, and the clock on the system that is evaluating it, are both set correctly.

The only way time zones would come into the picture is if your original timestamp was *not* in terms of UTC.  In that case, you'd need to know what the offset from UTC was in the context of where that timestamp was captured, at the time it was captured.  You'd use that information to convert the timestamp to UTC, then compare against UTC-Now as usual.

Answer (score 0):

I've added the following to my Laravel-model:

```
public function getCreatedAtAttribute($val) {
   return $val ? Carbon::parse($val) : null;
}
```

And this to TimeAgo-Component:

```
 <TimeAgo
     style={styles.timeago}
     time={msg.created_at.date + ' ' + msg.created_at.timezone}
 />
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to send the GMT time to your server then for each applications, you have to change it to the local time zone. Then you will have no problem with summer time saving and etc.

To get the local time zone in Java script, you can use below code to get differences between GMT and the local time in minutes:

```
new Date ().getTimezoneOffset ();//Returns -120 means that you are in the -2 zone
```